# Extend module with type alias

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to work with the [ocaml-inotify](https://github.com/vincenthz/ocaml-inotify) package. The relevant parts for this question can be defined as follows

```
module Inotify : sig
  type wd
  val int_of_wd : wd -> int
end = struct
  type wd = int
  let int_of_wd wd = wd
end
```

This work is taking place in a setuid script, and I want the inotify parts to be handled unprivileged, so I'm forking and then setuid-ing down to an unprivileged user in the child. However, this means that I need to pass the wd entities back to the parent through a pipe, and so need to serialise and deserialise them, requiring a `int_to_wd` function.

I've tried extending the module as follows:

```
module Rich_Inotify : sig 
  include module type of Inotify with type wd := int
  val wd_of_int : int -> wd
end = struct
  include Inotify
  let wd_of_int (wd:int) : wd = wd 
end
module Inotify = Rich_Inotify
```

However, the compiler complains that `wd` is an `int` and not a `wd`. How do I persuade it that these types are the same?

Comment: why do you need your extended module to know that the internal representation is int?

Comment: @didierc Technically, I don't. I need to be able to construct a `wd` from some serialised representation, the easiest way seemed to be using the fact that it's just an `int`. If you know of a better way to  manage this, I'd love to know!

Comment: My solution: fork the project, add the missing conversion primitive, push the patch back to the original project, and use your version in the mean time. I don't really understand why this function is not included from the start (most probably an oversight). If you need to deploy your code on a system where you cannot update the ocaml-inotify lib, you'll have to bundle your app with your own build somehow.

Comment: as @gasche said, trying to subvert the type system to force the type equivalence when `wd` is an abstract type is wrong. Your only hope is to roll out your own lib until this issue is resolved "upstream".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `Inotify` module is really defined with this signature, that is sealed with an abstract type, there is no way you will be able to break its abstraction to re-define it as an int. I mean that your signature `(module type of Foo with wd := int)` is clever and describes the interface you want, but the implementation `Foo` does *not* satisfy it: if the type-checker allowed that, there would be no type abstraction at all.

You should request the `ocaml-inotify` maintainer to add marshalling primitives (and possibly fork it locally to do that if you need). Instead of exposing the fact that `wd = int`, he or she could either publish conversion functions to and from `int` (so that future implementation changes could still implement these functions), or directly to and from `string` if you're only interested in marshalling and want to expose less internal details.

There is a solution that exposes more internal details that back-and-forth conversions to an abstract type, which is to use [private type abbreviations](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#s-private-types-abbrev):

```
sig
  type t = private int
  val mk : int -> t
end
```

This signature exposes that the internal representation is `int`, and allows to cast from `t` to `int` explicitly with `(foo :> int)` or `(foo : t :> int)` (you know that this is a no-op at runtime), but does not allow the inverse cast, so you are forced to use the `mk` function which, I assume, will do some kind of range checking to make sure that this is a valid descriptor.

(Some people will probably suggest that, as a workaround, you break the type safety of the language by using an unsafe cast that should not be named. Do not; this is bad advice.)